# Node webkit app - nw is undefined if it's navigated to local file system

Tags: angular, ionic3, nwjs

I have created an Ionic 3(A5) app. I am running this as node-webkit (NW.JS) app on Mac. If I navigate to a local filesystem '**nw**' does not work. Say something like this in package.json - "main": "file:////Users/Prasoon/Desktop/testnw/index.html", **nw** becomes undefined and I am unable to access any Node Apis. Any way to fix this?

However, things work fine if I just use "index.html" in package.json by placing index.html besides package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a reply from The Jared Wilcurt @TheJaredWilcurt on [gitter.im](http://gitter.im/nwjs)

only relative (../../../file.html), local (localhost:1234), and remote (http://example.com) addresses work in "main":

I used **localhost:8100** and it's all working!